# Need help (The ConnectionString property has not been initialized)

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I cannot fix the problem with The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. The problem is in this method:

```
try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        products.Update(dataSet, "Produktai");
                        offers.Update(dataSet, "Pasiulimai");
                        ts.Complete();
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
```

In the class constructor i already have a SqlDataAdapter and SqlCommandBuilder declared. My connection string is in App.config and it looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="server=ANDREW-PC\LTSMSQL;database=MarketDB; Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In my program I already assigned this connection string parameter to string variable. Here is a code sample:

```
private string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Any ideas how I can fix this error?

Comment: You never set the Connection property on your SqlCommand object. I believe you can also pass it into the constructor. This is why you're receiving the error.

Comment: I'm not sure how that code is supposed to work.  First you create a connection and then open it.  Then you create a SqlCommand object, but never associate the connection with it.  But also, you never use that SqlCommand object anywhere that I can see.

Comment: Adding to what @ChrisDunaway said, it's not clear what are you doing in the TransactionScope and where products or offers come from.

Comment: Start transactionscope BEFORE you open the connection

Comment: Here is the reason you don't know what's going wrong: `catch { }`. That discards the error message and continues as if nothing was wrong. But something is wrong. `catch` is for fixing errors, and `{ }` does not fix anything.

Comment: @ ohiodoug Connection property on SqlCommand, I never did it before and it worked perfectly. I even use it in code before it to read info from my database. I don't think the problem is in it. @ Marco Scabbiolo product and offers come from SqlDataAdapters.. wich are red from dataset but i don't think this makes any difference. @ Frode it won't help me. @ Dour High Arch catch will show me the same error i mentioned The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.. anyways thanks guys i think the error is somewhere in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found the problem. For some reasons my database was "read only" for me when I connect with visual studio. I have changed some settings in the database and now it works fine. Thanks for your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

The command isn't assigned to the connection. You need to use the sqlcommand constructor like so: `new SQLCommand(connection, "querystring")`. I also suggest you use a newer technology such as ORM. I used basic ADO.NET data access before I found Fluent NHibernate, and Fluent is so much easier to use :-)

Comment: thanks for offering new technology to me, but I have to do this work using this thing for my studies. I don't like it as well. I don't think it's necessary to change SQLCommand connection becouse I have used it before without any connections and it worked perfectly for me. (I used it in reading info from my database into datasets, same project.)

Comment: @Andrius I see, it's a little unusual he's got you using ADO.NET SQL, becuase it's both simple and pretty much redundant now.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using System.Transaction.TransactionScope? are you dealing with multiples transaction aware data sources such as sql server and oracle, where you need a transaction manager to coordinate the transaction? if not, then why don't you create a transaction from the connection?

```
   using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(" "))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var tran = connection.BeginTransaction();

                var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.Transaction = tran;


                //I dont know how the sql command relates to this  
                products.Update(dataSet, "Produktai");
                offers.Update(dataSet, "Pasiulimai");

                //commit
                tran.Commit(); 
            }
```